# Using a switch statement with getDay() method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, switch-statement

I want to use a switch statement with the `getDay()` method.

This is the switch statement I'm using. I want to return different data depending on the day.

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
}
```

And this is an example of the data I want to return for Monday.

```
 $scope.suggest1("monday-id", function(sItem) {
      if (sItem !== null) {
        $scope.suggestion = sItem.id;
        $scope.name = sItem.name;
        $scope.price = sItem.price;
        }
     });
```

I'm not sure how to link them, so any help would be great as I am still learning and couldn't find a similar question or example.

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a few details, but this is how i would do it.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('myctrl', [
  '$scope', function($scope) {
    var getDay, getDayDetails;
    getDayDetails = function(day) {
      var details;
      details = [
        {
          0: {name: 'sun',price: '0'},
          1: {name: 'mon',price: '1'},
          2: {name: 'tue',price: '2'},
          3: {name: 'wed',price: '3'},
          4: {name: 'thu',price: '4'},
          5: {name: 'fri',price: '5'},
          6: {name: 'sat',price: '6'}
        }
      ];
      return $scope.todayDetails = details[0][day];
    };
    getDay = function(date) {
      console.log("called");
      switch (date) {
        case 0:
          getDayDetails(0);
          break;
        case 1:
          getDayDetails(1);
          break;
        case 2:
          getDayDetails(2);
          break;
        case 3:
          getDayDetails(3);
          break;
        case 4:
          getDayDetails(4);
          break;
        case 5:
          getDayDetails(5);
          break;
        case 6:
          getDayDetails(6);
      } 
    };
    $scope.getDay = function(day) {
        $scope.day = getDay(day);
        return console.log("scope.day is ", $scope.day);
    };
    getDay(new Date().getDay());
  }
]);



<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <pre>{{todayDetails}}</pre>
</div>
```

(the html is just an example, just to give you an idea)
here's the pen:
https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/zdjGGr?editors=0010

or details can also be not an array, you have the ID in the object to match the day and you can iterate through all of the days and pull out the one you need to.

Comment: Can't you write `getDay` more simply as just `getDayDetails`?

Comment: Yeah can do, i just usually have small functions to do one simple thing, but thats just me, can easily be merged together

Comment: Yes I think this is something like what I am looking for! I will try this, thank you!

Comment: If it helped can you select the answer? Thanks